# How do I join 3 tables in this way

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

[image: Table 3]

And I want a resulting table that displays Movies.title, SUM(Bookings.price) and COUNT(BookingId).

I tried the code below, but keep getting the error:

> Column 'Movies.Title' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT Movies.Title, SUM(Bookings.Price) ASnewPrice, COUNT(Bookings.BookingId) AS Quantity 
FROM ((Orders
INNER JOIN Bookings ON Orders.BookingId = Bookings.BookingId)
INNER JOIN Movies ON Movies.MovieId = Bookings.MovieId)
WHERE UserId = @UserId AND Completed = @Completed 
ORDER BY Bookings.BookingId
```

Comment: Add `GROUP BY Movies.Title` before the ORDER BY.

Comment: But my Title is of type text and text won't compare.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Why that text data type for a movie title?

Comment: Thanks! Now it works, had to change from text to varcar(max) though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with this:

```
SELECT 
  Movies.Title, SUM(Bookings.Price) AS newPrice,COUNT(Bookings.BookingId) AS Quantity 
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN Bookings ON (Orders.BookingId = Bookings.BookingId)
INNER JOIN Movies ON (Movies.MovieId = Bookings.MovieId)
WHERE UserId = @UserId AND Completed = @Completed 
GROUP BY Movies.Title
ORDER BY Bookings.BookingId
```